# Boolean that can only be flipped to true

Tags: data-structures, types, unique

Is there a name for a data structure (read: boolean) that can only be moved from false to true, and not back to false?  Imagine something encapsulated like so:

```
private var _value = false
def value = _value
def turnOnValue() = value = true
```

And out of curiosity, are there any platforms that support it natively?  This seems like something somebody must have come across before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing a temporal property of a variable; rather than a data structure as such. The data type is a simple boolean, but it is how it is used that is interesting -- as a sort of 'latch' in time.

That kind of latch property on a boolean data type would make it an example of a **[linearly typed boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_type_system)**. Linear types, and other kinds of [uniqueness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_type) types are used to enforce temporal properties of variables -- e.g. that they can only be used once; or cannot be shared.

They're useful for enforcing at compile time that an action has happened (e.g. initialization) or having a compile-time proof that an object is not shared. Thus, they're most common in systems programming, where proofs of low level properties of this are key to correct software design.

Comment: If I'm reading the wikipedia post correctly, you can only read a linearly typed boolean once - doesn't seem useful for what the OP is requesting.

Comment: There are many different "linear" type systems and properties -- this is an example of one of them.

Answer (score 0):

In perl you have Tie Variables and you can build your on scalar value and make this kind of "type". But natively... maybe in Smalltalk can be possible to build something like this, or Prolog, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own data type

```
public final class CustomBoolean {
    private boolean value;
    public void setValue(boolean value){
        // Bitwise OR
        this.value |= value;
    }   

    public boolean getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Example ::

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
        CustomBoolean foo = new CustomBoolean();

        foo.setValue(false);
        System.out.println(foo.getValue());

        foo.setValue(true);
        System.out.println(foo.getValue());

        foo.setValue(false);
        System.out.println(foo.getValue());
}
```

The output would be ::

```
false
true
true
```

This means you'll have to call getValue() before doing any explicit boolean operations
ie

```
if(foo.getValue() && 1 == 1)
```

The example is written in Java.

Comment: @RichardPianka Oh okay. It's like... a flip flop... without the flop? I just saw your definition; I prefer my implementation more however, as it allows setting it generically like setValue(a && b), rather than if(a && b) turnOnValue()